# Is it possible to upload image to firebase storage using URL instead of SDK in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, image-uploading, firebase-storage

I'm trying to upload files to firebase storage from android app using url instead of SDK using Retrofit. This is my upload image method,

```
fun uploadImageToUrl() {
    val url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com/o/${bean.firebaseUid}/idProofs/${bean.documentTitle}.jpg/"
    var client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(url).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build()

    var service = retrofit.create(UploadService::class.java)

    var params = HashMap<String, RequestBody>()

    var reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), photoFile)
    var header = "Bearer ${bean.firebaseToken}"
    var body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", bean.documentTitle, reqFile)

    var response =  service.uploadDocument(header, body)

    response.enqueue(object: Callback<ResponseBody> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, response: Response<ResponseBody>?) {
            Log.e("Upload Response", response!!.message())
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.e("Upload Failed", t!!.localizedMessage)
        }

    })
}
```

This is the method in service interface.

```
interface UploadService {
  @Multipart
  @Headers("Accept: application/json")
  @POST("/?alt=media")
  fun uploadDocument(@Header("Authorization") header: String, @Part image: MultipartBody.Part): retrofit2.Call<ResponseBody>
}
```

But nothing is happening, no error messages, onResponse, onFailure methods not called, image not appearing.

Comment: Could you able to use Intercepter and do log the request and response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad. The URL should be like this

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com/o/${bean.firebaseUid}%2FidProofs%2F${bean.documentTitle}.jpg/

instead of this

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/xxxxxxx-xxxx.appspot.com/o/${bean.firebaseUid}/idProofs/${bean.documentTitle}.jpg/

I don't know why, but it's working.